# How to read data from more than one CSV file into line graph

Tags: c#, winforms, csv

Currently my code is able to select multiple csv files using `OpenFileDialog` and `MultiSelect = True`. But my graph seems to be only getting data from one csv file and not the others.

All my csv files only have 2 columns (X and Y Axis):

```
Value, Sector
5.55,1024
5.37,1536
5.73,2048
...
```

I need to be able to get data from multiple csv files, and come out with a graph that has multiple lines (e.g. 3 csv files = 3 lines shown in the graph).

Really appreciate if someone could help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably read [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to increase the odds that someone will help you. As it is right now, I don't think anyone is going to read through all your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you use `Multiselect`, you have to loop over all files selected by user instead of using the `OpenFile()` method as it works only for one file

```
if (ff.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //if ((myStream = ff.OpenFile()) != null)
    foreach (String file in ff.FileNames)
    {
        myStream = File.OpenRead(file);
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** about other parts of code which requires to be modified:

you have to use a `rrList` as `List<Read>` instead of just one rr.

**GraphDemo.cs**:

```
    Read rr;
    List<Read> rrList = new List<Read>(); // *** new

    void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog ff = new OpenFileDialog();

        ff.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
        ff.Filter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        ff.Multiselect = true;
        ff.FilterIndex = 1;
        ff.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (ff.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                rrList.Clear(); //***
                foreach (String file in ff.FileNames) //if ((myStream = ff.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream = File.OpenRead(file))
                    {
                        rr = new Read(myStream);
                        rr.fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);  // !!! new
                        string[] header = rr.get_Header();
                        List<string> lX = new List<string>();
                        List<string> lY = new List<string>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < header.Length; i++)
                        {
                            lX.Add(header[i]); lY.Add(header[i]);
                        }
                        //Populate the ComboBoxes
                        xBox.DataSource = lX;
                        yBox.DataSource = lY;
                        // Close the stream
                        myStream.Close();
                    }
                    rrList.Add(rr); //***
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                //Inform the user if we can't read the file
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Plot p = new Plot(rrList, xBox, yBox, chart); //*** use rrList instead of rr

    }
```

and **Plot class**:

```
class Plot
{
    public Plot(List<Read> rrList, ComboBox xBox, ComboBox yBox, Chart chart) //***
    {
        int indX = xBox.SelectedIndex;
        int indY = yBox.SelectedIndex;

        chart.Series.Clear(); //ensure that the chart is empty
        chart.Legends.Clear();
        Legend myLegend = chart.Legends.Add("myLegend"); // !!! new
        myLegend.Title = "myTitle"; // !!! new

        int i = 0; //series index
        foreach (Read rr in rrList)
        {
            float[,] data = rr.get_Data();
            int nLines = rr.get_nLines();
            int nColumns = rr.get_nColumns();
            string[] header = rr.get_Header();

            chart.Series.Add("Series" + i);
            chart.Series[i].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

            chart.Series[i].LegendText = rr.fileName; // !!! new

            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "{F2}";
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = header[indX];
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = header[indY];

            for (int j = 0; j < nLines; j++)
            {
                chart.Series[i].Points.AddXY(data[j, indX], data[j, indY]);
            }

            i++; //series index
        }
    }
}
```

add to `Read` class:

```
public string fileName { get; set; } // !!! new
```

Note: your code approach is not so good, for example the Plot should be a void method inside a its class and not a constructor as you have to re-create a new instance of Plot each time you want to draw a new plot which is not required. There are many other tips there... but it works

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I know if i need to change anything from my Plot.cs or Read.cs? I've tried adding in your code but it only show 1 line in the graph even though I've selected 2 csv files.

Comment: yes, you have to update other parts of code. see my edit

Comment: Yup it works now! Thanks so much. Another short question, how am I able to add in the legends at the sides based on the input file name? Have some problem with the "Chart1.Legends.Add".

Comment: Accepted. I couldn't get the legend to be displayed based on the files opened. E.g. Opened 1.csv and 2.csv but the legends are not shown accordingly.

Comment: you have to keep filename as a new property in Read class and use it during plot. i'll post an update to code `chart.Series[i].LegendText = rr.fileName;`

Comment: Tested and works. Thanks a lot for your time!! Really appreciate your hard work and patience on this :)

Comment: Hi S.Serp, I need help with reading string from the csv file and plot graph using the string data. Really appreciate if you can help me with that question. Thanks :)